# Hide on bootstrap-collapse is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-collapse.js v2.0.3.
I have 2 queries on show/hiding accordian.
1. Need to collapse the first accordian body expanded by default.
   To show the first accordian, I am calling `$('#Head_1').collapse ('show');` but it is not working.
2. Clicking on `div#Head_2` need to collapse the expanded and need to expand `Head_2`. For this I am calling

```
$('#Head_1').collapse ('hide');
$('#Head_2').collapse ('show');
```

In this case `Head_2` getting expanded but `Head_1` is not getting collapsed.

```
<div id="AccordianViewList" class="accordion" >
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#AccordianViewList" href="#Head_1">Head_1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body collapse in" id="Body1">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            <ul class="unstyled" >
                <li class="listItem inFocus" >item1</li>
                <li class="listItem" >item2</li>
                <li class="listItem" >item3/li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#AccordianViewList"  href="#Head_2">Head_2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body in collapse" id="Head_2">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            <ul class="unstyled" >
                <li class="listItem inFocus" >item4</li>
                <li class="listItem" >item5</li>
                <li class="listItem" >item6</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#AccordianViewList" href="#Head_3">Head_3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body in collapse" style="height: auto;"  id="Head_3">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            <ul class="unstyled" >
                <li class="listItem inFocus" >item7</li>
                <li class="listItem" >item8</li>
                <li class="listItem" >item9</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('Head_1')` you have missed the `#` for id selector.

Comment: @AmitJoki not OP but his/her markup....you can see that there are `id="Head_2...."`

Comment: Yeah, didn't see that. Mean while OP means Original Poster

Comment: It was mistake in the above code. Actually I am calling like this.
$('#Head_3').collapse ('hide');
$('#Head_2').collapse ('show');

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `in` class from any accordion group you don't want expanded on load.

So, for example, if you only want your `#Head_1` group to be open, edit your code as such:

```
...
<div class="accordion-body collapse in" id="Head_1">
...
<div class="accordion-body collapse" id="Head_2">
...
<div class="accordion-body collapse" id="Head_3">
...
```

You also have a mismatch on the id of your first group. you are using `Body1` in one area and `Head_1` in the other. Change one so they match.

```
<div class="accordion-heading">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#AccordianViewList" href="#Head_1">Head_1</a>
</div>
<div class="accordion-body collapse in" id="Head_1">
```

Live example: http://www.bootply.com/9SYyp5NiLH

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('#Head_1').collapse('hide');
$('#Head_2').collapse('show');
```

You should prefix a `#` to the id to select that particular element.

Answer (score 0):

My work around has been to replace:

```
$('#Selector').collapse('hide');
```

with

```
$('#Selector').addClass('collapse');
```

EDIT:  this is just for the first call though.

```
$('#Selector').collapse('hide');
```

works for the subsequent calls.  In my case I just make the call to both in my function

Answer (score 0):

Just add and id to every tag link:

```
 <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a id="link1" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#AccordianViewList" href="#Head_1">Head_1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body collapse in" id="Head_1">
```

And then call the click event

```
if($('#link1').hasClass('collapsed')){
    $('#link1').click();
}
```